# Downloading NuGet packages for self hosted feed

Tags: package, feed, nuget

The NuGet web site has an excellent article for hosting your own NuGet feed. In our case we are an IT shop that needs to fully vet packages before making them available to our development staff so we would like to host our own feed which will provide "approved packages". One thing the article glosses over is how to pull down the nuget packages for hosting. So for example if we want to host EntityFramework 5.0.0 so our developers can use it how do we get the package without using NuGet as policy prevents NuGet accessing hosts past our firewall?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're not completely cut off from nuget.org, you could use [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget/download) to host your network's feed. Since ProGet allows you to both create multiple feeds and also to connect to other NuGet feeds, you could create one feed, say "NuGet Cached", and then a "Developer" feed, and specify the same package storage location for both feeds. The trick would be to set up a connector to nuget.org on the "NuGet Cached" feed, then use the Pull Package feature to download the hosted NuGet packages to your local feed.

This way, developers would set up Visual Studio (or whatever tool they use to get the packages) to point to the "Developer" feed which only has the packages you have explicitly pulled down (since both feeds store packages in the same location). You could also add deny privileges to the "NuGet Cached" feed such that they can't connect to it at all.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a host server (sounds like you have, but if not it's installing and hosting a [NuGet.Service](http://nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server)).
2. Confirm it's working by visiting the host (should see a very simple dashboard saying the Nuget service number, etc)
3. open VisualStudio options, "Pakcage Manager"->"Package Sources"
4. Add your internal host here (probably something like `http://internalsvr/nuget`)

Then you should be able to install packages form that source locally. also, you can push things up there, or place the packages in the `~/packages/` directory and they will automatically be listed in the service.

Comment: Thanks for your response Brad. Our issue is getting the packages we want to deploy to our own host for things like EntityFramework. They don't make it easy to get to the packages without NuGet. We can only use NuGet behind the firewall.

Comment: Assuming _someone_ has gotten the package (off-site or took their laptop home) the packages are cached in the solution's folder which can then be uploaded to the local (internal) server. other than that, you may be able to go to github/bitbucket and download the source and compile your own package and upload that.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try out http://www.myget.org or use any of the other software out there.